# cross-NG GCC 4.6.3 configure failure: unable to find a usable PPL (while it's present)

Tags: cross-compiling

I'm trying to build cross-NG for ARM and i586 architectures. `ct-ng build` fails when trying to compile GCC. I already installed PPL version 1.0-1. Also tried version 0.11.2-2. I can'r understand why configuration script of GCC can't find PPL, while is already there...

All same result:

```
...
[CFG  ]    checking for the correct version of gmp.h... yes
[CFG  ]    checking for the correct version of mpfr.h... yes
[CFG  ]    checking for the correct version of mpc.h... yes
[CFG  ]    checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... yes
[CFG  ]    checking for PWL_handle_timeout in -lpwl... yes
[CFG  ]    checking for version 0.11 (revision 0 or later) of PPL... no
[ERROR]    configure: error: Unable to find a usable PPL.  See config.log for details.
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing pass-1 core C compiler'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@172]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_cc_core_backend[scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh@343]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_cc_core_pass_1[scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh@88]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@598]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      'docs/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 7:27.12)
```

In case that matters, my box:

```
uname -m x86_64
distro: archlinux
gcc -v: gcc version 4.7.1 20120721 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Crosstool-NG [downloads & builds its dependencies on its own](http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2012-07/msg00044.html).  In ct-ng menuconfig, there's this note :

```
  │ │    ()  Extra addons                                                 │ │  
  │ │          *** WARNING !!!                                            │ │  
  │ │          ***   For glibc >= 2.8, it can happen that the tarballs    │ │  
  │ │          ***   for the addons are not available for download.       │ │  
  │ │          ***   If that happens, bad luck... Try a previous version  │ │  
  │ │          ***   or try again later... :-(
```

Maybe the download server was momentarily down or your network connection flaked out. "Try again later" ?

Another thing to try is selecting different versions of PPL in ct-ng menuconfig under Companion libraries.  In my case, I had selected a combination of gcc and other versions that crosstool does not support. Try using the stock generic arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi configuration without modification. That builds for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IIRC I changed version of PPL and it worked. Then for some other reason (that I don't remember now) moved to buildroot. It works fine. I don't remember details (it was 10 month ago :)

Comment: I'm happy to try to help :)  AFAIK buildroot uses crosstool-ng to build its toolchain. What advantages does buildroot offer over crosstool alone?  I'd considered buildroot but it wasn't clear what its benefits are.